# Sentence similarity using word2vev

Tags: nlp, word2vec, similarity

Basically what I want is to know how similar a specific sentence/document is to my training corpus.

I think I might have half an idea of how to approach this but I'm not too sure.
So my idea is to calculate an average vector for the document and then somehow calculating the similarity like that. I just don't know how I would calculate the similarity then.

So say I have a training corpus filled with text about dogs. If I then want to check how similar the sentence, "The airplane has 100 seats.", is to the training corpus I want is to output a low similarity score.

Answer (score 0):

This is a semantic textual similarity problem. You can have a look at state-of-the-art models here https://nlpprogress.com/english/semantic_textual_similarity.html

Usually you would pass your document in an encoder to create a representation (embedding of the document) then do the same with the sentence (usually using the same encoder). The vectors could be fed into further layers for further processing. A similarity metric like cosine could then be used on the vectors (embeddings) or a joint final representation could be used for classification.

You can use some pretrained language models in the encoding step and fine tune them for your use-case.

Comment: Would I be able to do something similar for LDA or is that a different ball game?